# How to make pxssh expect other prompt in python

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect

I am using [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pxssh.html) to ssh to a device. Below is the code:

```
session = pxssh.pxssh()

if not session.login(ip, "username", "password"):
    print("SSH session failed on login")
    print(str(session))
    return False
else:
    print("SSH session login successfull")
    return True
```

I tested this locally on other device which has below prompt:

```
username@Machine54:~/
```

I then tried it on the server which has

```
username@server:/#
```

But it throws error:

```
Error could not synchronize with original prompt
```

How do I modify the code to ssh into server.

Comment: Give [Exscript](https://github.com/knipknap/exscript) a look.

Comment: Give a [mcve] and the full Exception backtrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pxssh.login` has an optional parameter `original_prompt`, which depending on your release is probably the pattern `[#$]`, namely a hash or a dollar. This is described in the documentation as *very optimistic and easily fooled*. You should try setting one that is closer to your expected prompt, eg:

```
if not session.login(ip, "username", "password",
                     original_prompt=r'@[^:]+:.*?/#?'):
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you share link to the documentation where this is defined. Also, in original_prompt do we need to define regex pattern

Comment: Python comes with the `pydoc` command to list documentation that is part of any Python class, so you can type `pydoc pexpect` and `pydoc pexpect.pxssh` for the documentation.  `original_prompt` is used in `expect()` so it is a regex.